# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str (the for loop method works, the lambda expression method doesnt)

Tags: python

Hey I have a working code which is this:

```
two_days_ago_chatted_visitors = None
yesterdays_chatted_visitors = None
chat_count = None
for x in apichat_data_bydate:
    if x["date"] == two_days_ago.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"):
        two_days_ago_chatted_visitors = x['visitors_with_conversation_count']
    else:
        yesterdays_chatted_visitors = x['visitors_with_conversation_count']
        chat_count = x['conversation_count']
```

But I have been instructed to make my code simpler, and use something like this:

```
two_days_ago_str = two_days_ago.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
data_for_two_days_ago = filter(
    lambda data_for_day: data_for_day['date'] == two_days_ago_str, apichat_data_bydate
)
two_days_ago_chatted_visitors = data_for_two_days_ago['visitors_with_conversation_count']

yesterday_str = two_days_ago.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
data_for_yesterday = filter(
    lambda data_for_day: data_for_day['date'] == yesterday_str, apichat_data_bydate
)
yesterdays_chatted_visitors = data_for_yesterday['visitors_with_conversation_count']
chat_count = data_for_yesterday['conversation_count']
```

But now the new code does not work and gives an error:

`TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

How can I fix the error in my second block? Putting the first block is not an option

Comment: Explicit is better than implicit. Why not use the for loop?

Comment: post full traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data_for_two_days_ago` is a list, `filter(func, list)` returns a list.

But then you do:

```
data_for_two_days_ago['visitors_with_conversation_count']
```

And so you get the `list indices must be integers, not str`.

Maybe you want to write `data_for_two_days_ago = filter(...)[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think the first block is simpler. As Dchoni pointed "explicit is better than implicit".

Using `lambda` the things become somwhat obscure. In your `for` loop you can easier comment a line, put a break, or maybe use a `print`, so it will be easier to debug and observe how the code actually works. Especially for beginners it helps to get better insight and learn faster.

Also the father of Python Guido van Rossum wanted to remove `lambda` from Python. Here is a [blog post](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196) from him regarding this feature.

So rethink if you're question is really: How can I fix the error in my second block? or Should I really use the second block?.

Beyond that there is a saying "Don't fix it if it ain't broken".

Comment: The question is how can i fix my second block. I have been instructed to use the second block, and make that block.